# how to communicate between tabhost and actvities

Tags: android, android-tabhost

I create my code like that:

```
        final TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();

        tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("Month")
                .setIndicator("Month")
                .setContent(new Intent(this, MonthView.class)));
```

How can i communicate with tabhost in monthview class?

Answer (score 3):

Use the [**`getParent()`**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getParent%28%29) method on `MonthView`.